# Filtering in-memory copies of SQLAlchemy relationships with primaryjoin

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have the following models:

```py
class BaseModel(DeclarativeBase):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]


class Parent(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "parent"

    notes: Mapped[list["Notes"]] = relationship(
        "Notes", 
        primaryjoin="""and_(
            Parent.id == Notes.parent_id,
            Notes.child_id == None
        )"""
    )


class Child(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "child"

    notes: Mapped[list["Notes"]]
    parent_id = Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(Parent.id))
    notes: Mapped[list["Notes"]]


class Notes(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "child"

    parent_id = Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(Parent.id))
    child_id = Mapped[None | int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(Child.id))
```

This mostly works. However when I add to `child.notes`, they appear in `parent.notes` until I call `flush(parent)`:

```py
db: Sesssion
parent = Parent(name="Annie")
db.flush()
child = Child(parent_id=parent.id)
db.flush()
child.notes.append(Note(name="Test note"))
assert not parent.notes  # Will fail
db.refresh(parent)
assert not parent.notes  # Will succeed
```

I figured out that I can use `lazy="dynamic"` which forces the relationship to always query the database. But that changes semantics and is apparently deprecated according to documentation, as does it's replacement .

What is the simplest way to get the ORM to filter the in-memory state while retaining normal lazy relationship semantics (`parent.notes.append()`, etc)?